# Is there a statistical test that can compare two ordered lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, statistics

I would like to get a statistical test statistic to compare two lists. Suppose my Benchmark list is

```
Benchmark = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
```

and I have two other lists

```
A =  [g,c,b,a,f,e,d]
C = [c,d,e,a,b,f,g]
```

I want the test to inform me  which list is closer to the Benchmark. The test should consider the absolute location, but also the relative location for example it should penalize the fact that in list `A` 'g' is at the start but in the benchmark it is at the end(how far is something from its true location), but also it should also reward the fact that 'a' and 'b' are close to each other in list `C` just like in the `Benchmark`.
A and C are always shuffled Benchmark. I would like a statistical test or some kind of metric that informs me that the orderings of  list `A` , `B` and `C` are not  statistically different from that of the Benchmark but that of a certain list `D` is significantly different at a certain threshold or p-value  such as 5%.  And even among the lists `A`,`B` and `C`, the test should perfectly outline which ordering is closer to the Benchmark.

Comment: Are `A` and `C` always shuffled `Benchmark`? That is, they contain the same exact items, but a certain permutation has been applied to them?

Comment: Also, if you need an answer for *"Which list is closer to the Benchmark?"*, you don't need a statistical test, just a simple metric will do, like `def dist(a, b) -> float:`. I have a solid idea about how that function might look like.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan  yes, A and C are always shuffled Benchmark but a certain permutation has been applied to them, The reason I was asking about a statistical test is that lets say  the lists have 100 elements ,  how would we consider a threshold good or bad, how would we know that list A is statistically significantly different from Benchmark while C is not.

Comment: That's a great point. It would definitely help if you did not withhold this piece of information from us, because it might help us solve your problem quicker. You specifically asked for *"Which list is closer to Benchmark?"*, which is not actually what you're trying to find out.

Comment: By the way, even statistical tests require you to specify a `confidence level`, which is the equivalent of a `threshold` which you'd like to not be a parameter of your system. It most likely will have to be.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan do you think my question is better now??

Comment: Certainly James, great job (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you come to the conclusion that a metric will suffice, here you go:

```
def dist(a, b):
    perm = []
    for v in b:
        perm.append(a.index(v))
        
    perm_vals = [a[p] for p in perm]
        
    # displacement
    ret = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(perm):
        ret += abs(v - i)
    
    # coherence break
    current = perm_vals.index(a[0])          
    for v in a[1:]:
        new = perm_vals.index(v)
        ret += abs(new - current) - 1
        current = new
    
    return ret
```

I've created a few samples to test this:

```
import random

ground_truth = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
samples = []
for i in range(7):
    samples.append(random.sample(ground_truth, len(ground_truth)))
    
samples.append([0, 6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2])
samples.append([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
samples.append([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

def dist(a, b):
    perm = []
    for v in b:
        perm.append(a.index(v))
        
    perm_vals = [a[p] for p in perm]
        
    # displacement
    ret = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(perm):
        ret += abs(v - i)
    
    # coherence break
    current = perm_vals.index(a[0])          
    for v in a[1:]:
        new = perm_vals.index(v)
        ret += abs(new - current) - 1
        current = new
    
    return ret
        
    
for s in samples:
    print(s, dist(ground_truth, s))
```

The metric is a cost, that is, the lower it is, the better. I designed it to yield `0` iff the permutation is an identity. The job left for you, that which none can do for you, is deciding how strict you want to be when evaluating samples using this metric, which definitely depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks a million for the answer, it is quite instrumental in getting me set on the task I am trying to perform. However this method is geared towards a permutation of numbers  is there any way to engineer it towards a list of strings.. which Is what I i actually need

Comment: @Jamesj Have you tried it with a list of strings? As far as I know, it should work with any objects which have `__eq__` (`a == b`) implemented, such as `int`, `float` or `str`.

That is, I claim that it should work for arrays like `GT = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']` and `A = ['cd', 'ab', 'ef']` with `B = ['ef', 'cd', 'ab']` for example. The trick is using the `perm.index(...)` function, which always returns an `int` (index) - it does not matter whether it's indexing integers, floats, strings or whatever.

Comment: So there's something weird about the coherence break part , sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't for example `
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-662027690b9a> in <module>()
----> 1 dist([5,0,1,2,3,4,7],[5,3,0,4,2,1,7] )

<ipython-input-108-90dafecff5ef> in dist(a, b)
     12     current = perm.index(a[0])
     13     for v in a[1:]:
---> 14         new = perm.index(v)
     15         ret += abs(new - current) - 1
     16         current = new

ValueError: 7 is not in list`

Comment: Lemme check that out.

Comment: I see the issue, I'll fix it soon.

Comment: @Jamesj I updated `def dist` in both code sections. I believe this should fix your problem, does it?